# Zend form upload multiple file with same name as array gives fileMaxSize Error

Tags: php, jquery, forms, file, zend-framework

i want to upload multiple files with zend form..i make my form with a class that reads an INI file and generate a form object. here is the code for my file element

```
elements.idea_sf1_image.type = "file"
     elements.idea_sf1_image.options.isArray = true
     elements.idea_sf1_image.options.maxFileSize=512600
     elements.idea_sf1_image.options.label = "MAIN_IMAGE"
     elements.idea_sf1_image.options.nolabel =true
     elements.idea_sf1_image.options.validators.extension.validator = "Extension"
     elements.idea_sf1_image.options.destination = "_upload/userphoto"
     elements.idea_sf1_image.options.isImage = true
     elements.idea_sf1_image.options.required = true
     elements.idea_sf1_image.options.ignore = true
     elements.idea_sf1_image.options.valuedisabled=true
     elements.idea_sf1_image.options.selectButtonName=" انتخاب تصویر"
     elements.idea_sf1_image.options.uploadButtonName=" تغییر تصویر"
     elements.idea_sf1_image.options.removeButtonName ="حذف تصویر"
     elements.idea_sf1_image.options.validators.extension.options.extension = "jpg,jpeg,png,JPG,JPEG,PNG,BMP,bmp,GIF,gif"
```

as you can see i put a maxfile size validator.
in my view i render my element as follow:

```
<?php  $this->form->idea_sf1_image->render(); ?>
```

when my form is posted form validation always return "Max file size is exceeded error".
when i dumped my form posted data in controller i noticed that form send a data named MAX_FILE_SIZE with value of 1. does any one know why my code is showing this error?
by the way my form is dynamic.it means user can add multiple files with pressing an + button and i copy file input code at the end of form.

### **UPDATE**:

well i found the problem and solve it...
i had an form object before...and when i instantiate another form object from above ini file and add its elements to other form object,it put a hidden input named "MAX_FILE_SIZE" equal to zero instead of 512600.
so i tried to figure it out why it does not set it correctly.i did not found any solution but i figure it out that MAX_FILE_SIZE with zero value prevent browser to send file to server correctly. i just change MAX_FILE_SIZE value in view file using JQuery and now its working just fine.
but i still do not know why zend form act like this when adding a file element object to it.

Comment: Can you provide source code how do you generate a form from this ini file?

Comment: well it a big library that include multiple classes for all kind of input types so its not possible to provide them

Comment: Unfortunately then it is impossible to tell you what goes wrong in this big library. Obviuosly that the maxFileSize parameter is set to 1 instead of 512600. You should check also yout `php.ini` settings for `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize`

Comment: i already checked 'post_max_size' and 'upload_max_filesize'.i will check my library to find out why maxFileSize is set to 1 and will let you know the results.

Comment: @Gennadiy Litvinyuk  post_max_size and upload_max_filesize are just fine in php.ini

Comment: So long I can not see how the form is created from ini, (maybe also the html generation of the form) I see no way to help you, except of wild guessing